# Get user ip address for geolock (not 192.168 address)

Tags: php, ip, local, geo

Im geo locking our program, we have a service that returns the country code for us. But if someone is behind a router, they have a local 192.168.x.x address, and this tells me nothing. Is there a way to find out their address at the router? I could do a trace, but then i need to program logic myself about which ip is useful and which are not. I'm doing this code fromt he server in php, and our client web app is in javascript. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: If your software is running on a server then the server will see the router address, not the local address. Have you found this to be a problem, or is this hypothetical?

Comment: a little of both. i forsee it being an issue, and i thought that the php _SERVER tag returned the server address, not the client. maybe i read the documentation wrong...

Comment: Google "what is my ip". Some of these pages even return the country code for you.

Comment: yes, ive done that. right now i use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; but it returns "::1". so it cant be right.

Comment: You need to fetch one of those pages and parse the contents to get the ip address.

Comment: @japes Interesting - that's the IPv6 loopback address. Are you running your browser on the same machine as your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_real_ip() {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARED_FOR']))
    {
        $client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARED_FOR'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else
    {
        $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $client_ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For server based software the PHP variable $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will give the address of the client. For clients behind a router their address will be translated by the router firmware, so the server will see the router's public IP address, not the client's local private address.

All this is further confused by the possible presence of intervening proxy servers which may or may not tell you what their client address is. You can look at $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWRDED_FOR'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], if they're present. If not, you'll have to make do with the proxy address.